# Setup VPN to accept incoming connection on VMplayer

Tags: windows, vmware, vpn

I have VMware player 5.0.2 installed in Win8 64bit host and running Win7 as Guest.

I'm trying to set up Win7 guest to receive VPN connection (PPTP), but it is not working, the VPN connection request keeps being disconnected.

Is it possible to create VPN on a bridged network? I am aiming to get the Guest Win7 to accept incoming VPN connections and allow the Win7 Guest to access the outside through VPN. Any clue or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can setup VPN connection on a bridged network. It is possible to dial from my XP machine to a VPN server set up on a windows server 2008 which was running on VMWare.